# Odd slowdown in file transfer using tcpClient

Tags: windows, vb.net, file, tcpclient

I'm building some classes for network communication using tcpClient. I have the tcpserver class accepting connections and shuffling them off to background threads so it can continue accepting connections on that port. I can connect to the server with multiple clients and do file transfers from the server to the clients. Running both the server and clients on my dev machine, I'm getting nice file transfer speeds (160 mbps or so - I'm using large packet sizes).

I was testing larger and larger file transfers from multiple clients, and noticed an odd thing - when trying to send large files (>3gig), about half way through the transfers began to slow and fluctuate. If I try to send my 3 gig test file (an .iso), while also transferring largish files (>500meg) using two or three other clients, also running on my dev machine, the .iso's transfer may slow to a crawl and stay there... as slow as 1 meg per second or less, even after the other clients have completed receiving their files. It could also, for no reason I can see pick up in speed again and fluctuate between 30 and 80 meg per second.

There are no errors, and having sifted through the code, I just have no idea where the slowdown could be happening.

Could this be a thread priority thing? I have to use large variable types to handle the some of the elements of the file transfer (an int64 for the file size, another to record the amount of bytes that have come in so far, ect)... could I be seeing the slowdown as the values of these variables get larger?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok... if I don't actually write the file bytes when they reach my client, I have none of these problems at all. Something's happening when I try to actually write the bytes to a file in the client. I'm just using FileStream to write an array of bytes...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered what happens to the data between being received and being written to the disk? i.e. Are you caching this in a memory array, if so what is the memory usage profile of your applications in relation to your total system memory?

Comment: Also, I've noticed that the slowdown seems to happen when I'm copying the >3gig .iso just as the file size crosses the 2 gig boundary. from there till the end of the file, I have lots of strangeness. Network speed fluctuations (which I think are file write speed issues)...

Comment: I'm reading bytes in using a networkstream and a byte array. When the byte array is full of the current packet, I hand it off to a filestream to be written.

Comment: With the server and three clients running in visual studio, it's using 28 meg or so. I've got 12 gig in the machine.

Comment: I'm using windows 7... drm maybe?

Comment: I'd be v.surprised if it's DRM. It seems like a very odd error. I was one of the writers of networkComms.net, an open source c# network communication framework, and although we had lots of problems that certainly wasn't one of them. My advice would be run both the client and server through a performance analyser. The one in visual studio 2010 would be best. Then just look at the time slices where it is slow, that might help point to a performance bottleneck.

Comment: It's something on my machine. I just threw together a quick little app that shows the file copy from one place on my computer to another using two file streams, a progress bar and showing the bytes per second in a status strip. There are bursts of speed, but also slowdowns to below 3 meg per second. Sometimes the file copied very fast, and sometimes those slowdowns were more lengthy, and really increased the length of the file copy in a significant way. Well... at least now I know it's not a problem with my network comunications class. Lol. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it's actually hardware limitations... I increases the size of the write buffer (in the client only) to 10% of the file size, or 3.2 meg max and I got nice smooth 250 meg per second transfer of that .iso until I cross the 2 gig boundary, after which it drops to 90-100 meg per second or so. Throttling the bandwidth to 25 meg per second, and transferring large files with three clients at a time produces nice, smooth 25 meg transfers all the way through... And I can live with that. I'm never going to allow 25 meg transfers per session in any case... lol.

Comment: Just thought you might like to know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issues you did when writing filestreams across a LAN. assuming you are using a filestream to write the file. try switching the access between write and read/write access. I believe it's read/write access which doesn't do a good job of flushing the changes. Also I like seeing the filesize grow as the file is written, but setting the file length before writing the file seems to give better performance.